# Java dynamic gui

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I'm studying java at school and we are doing some basic java programming.
Basically i had to do 2 class (1 oblject class "Book" containing some information and a second class that contains a Book vector and some basic methods).
I had no problem with the code, but once i have to create the GUI my teacher said me to do a "static gui" meaning a gui that doesn't change during time showing one book by time.
The idea of a static gui doesn't appeal me so here is the question.
Are there any ways of doing a dynamic gui?
By dynamic i mean a gui that can show as much books as much are instantiated in the vector something that interacts with the final user.
Thanks for the help and feel free to ask me for any further information.
P.S. we are using netbeans.

Comment: Yes, you can have UI with lists.  Listen to your teacher and start with a static one.  When you have it working, you can try better solutions.

Comment: While your Question is interesting, it is too broad for Stack Overflow. Questions here should be narrowly focused on a specific issue that can be answered with a specific solution. Open-ended discussions are to be avoided.

Comment: I already did the static one. Are there any online guide?